# ASP.NET MVC - Redirect(); is not redirecting correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have something like this:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Login()
   {
      return Redirect("http://localhost/");
   }
}
```

I would want it to redirect user to that page, but it keeps redirecting it to

```
http://localhost/Account/http://localhost/
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Redirect to application root :

```
Redirect("~/");
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're trying to redirect it to the home page given that code. In which case, you should probably just use RedirectToAction, as follows:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Comment: No. Actually i simplified that. In reality action Login() gets returnUrl, then encodes it, then redirects it. So it isn't THAT simple. :-)

Comment: You might want to put something like that in your question, then.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i solved my problem. In reality i was passing encoded url into my Redirect(); method. It seems that this method can only work on unencoded versions of links.